# It's possible to pass a variable on attach_library in a template on Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

I need to pass a variable to a library called on a Twig template, is this possible?

```
{{ attach_library('theme/some-library') }}
```

Comment: You could also do this from a preprocess hook.

Comment: You want a variable that will be read as Javascript in the client's browser? You could print a script tag with the variable. And the library would read it from the DOM.

Comment: Right, I was wondering if there was a more fancy way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load()
 */ 

function my_module_node_load($nodes) {
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      if ($node->getType() == 'article') { // is of article content type
        $data_passer = &drupal_static('my_module_node_field_name');
        // use &drupal_static to pass value between hooks. 
        $data_passer = $node->field_name->value;
      }
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments()
 */
function my_module_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
    if (!empty(&drupal_static('my_module_node_field_name'))) {
      $data_passer = &drupal_static('my_module_node_field_name'); 
      $node_field_name = $data_passer;
      $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_variable'] = $node_field_name;     
    }
  }
}
```

.js

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_behaviour = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      alert(drupalSettings.my_variable); //alerts passed in node field_name

    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there is a way of doing it directly from the template, although I ended up using a preprocess hook.

Comment: @Flupkear from template file there isn't, unless you print the value in an attribute and then pick it up with jQuery. Ex: `<div class"something" variable="{{ content.field_variable.0 }}"> {{ content.field_some_field }} </div>` and in jQuery `var variable = $('.something').attr('variable');`

Answer (score -1):

I have passed my variable in twig like this:

```
{{ attach_library('theme/library' ~ variable ) }}
```